# Are virtual properties lazy loaded in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some virtual properties a User. E.g. I have an `ActiveOrderCount` property. The property can be a bit slow because it requires some calculations, so my question is if the property `ActiveOrderCount` is evaluated when I retrieve a list of users, or if it is first evaluated when I ask for the property value?

**Update:**
Sorry didn't provide a code example.

The property could look like this

```
def active_order_count
  self.orders.active.count
end
```

**Update 2**

A comment reminded me that they are not properties, but methods, so to answer my question myself, they wont be automatically loaded.

Comment: why would it be evaluated automatically? how did you implement it?

Comment: Code, or no help. :) There is no such a thing as virtual properties in ruby - everything is a method, and those are not executed until they are called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wont be automatically evaluated, must be done explicitly.

BTW, you should consider to stick with Ruby's syntax conventions :)

Camelcase is for modules/classes only (and self is implicit so not required)